# Submit form using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, django

Hello hello javascript newbie here.

I am trying to submit a form with pure javascript but failing :

```
var myform = document.getElementById('js-post-form');
myform.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open(myform.method, myform.action, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', cookies['csrftoken']);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

    request.onload = function () {
      if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
        console.log("ready");
        var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        console.log('success');
      } else {
        console.log("not ready yet");
      };
    };
    request.onerror = function() {
      console.log("connection error");
    };
    request.send();
  });

});
```

What am I missing ?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not sending anything to the server. Request body should be sent with `send()` method. Try this:

```js
var myform = document.getElementById('js-post-form');
myform.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open(myform.method, myform.action, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', cookies['csrftoken']);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

    request.onload = function () {
      if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
        console.log("ready");
        var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        console.log(data); // returns the dictionnary { selected_elements:[] } 
        console.log('success');
      } else {
        console.log("not ready yet");
      };
    };
    request.onerror = function() {
      console.log("connection error");
    };
    request.send(myform); // Passed the form to be send with request body.
  });

});
```

Mozilla Docs on [`send()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) method.

Comment: aaaah how I wish you were right ! So I added `myform` to `request.send()` and I still get an empty list... :(

Comment: did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Using `FormData`  was the answer. Thank you Nalin for putting me on the right track !

the JS :

```
var myform = document.getElementById('js-post-form');
myform.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    var formData = new FormData(myform);
    e.preventDefault();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open(myform.method, myform.action, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', cookies['csrftoken']);
    request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

    request.onload = function () {
      if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
        console.log("ready");
        var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        console.log(data); // returns the dictionnary { selected_elements:[] } 
        console.log('success');
      } else {
        console.log("not ready yet");
      };
    };
    request.onerror = function() {
      console.log("connection error");
    };
    request.send(formData);
  });

});
```